# mysql mecab plugin not working on myisam engine

Tags: mysql, plugins, full-text-search, mecab

Recently I happened to check the mecab plugin on mysql.

On [mysql manual page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search-mecab.html), it says that mecab plugin works on myisam and innodb engine.

However I found that it is not working on myisam engine.

When I created the full text index using mecab plugin on the table made with myisam engine, the result of the full search always returns the all records in table.

But on the table made with innodb engine, full search feature works fine.

So does anybody have some experience on mecab plugin on the myisam engine?

Regards.